# Realm in today extension

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I installed Realm manually, and it is working on my main app. But on the today extension, i can't even import RealmSwift. I apologise if this question is a newbie question, but I've been searching the web and I can't find a proper updated version. I have read https://realm.io/news/tutorial-sharing-data-between-watchkit-and-your-app/ but it's written a year ago and it does not work anymore.

So how do I go about using realm to share data between the main app and the extension?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though that article is quite old (It's not even using Realm Swift! It's using the Objective-C version bridged to Swift!), the principles of using Realm with iOS 8 extensions haven't changed to the point where the information in there has become outdated.

The main points to consider:

1. For all intents and purposes, a Today Extension is a wholly separate app from your main app. It needs to be able to be fully self-contained in its operation.
2. As long as you're using the dynamic framework version, you can link one copy of `RealmSwift.framework` to both your main app, and the extension.
3. You need to make sure you've set your Realm file to be saved in the `containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier` URL. This is the only place where your main app and the extension can share files.
4. Because the Today extension is technically a separate app, make sure any `Object` subclasses you've made are included in both your main app, and your extension's 'Compile Sources' build phases.

Please let me know if you need any more clarification. :)

Comment: Hi TiM, Thanks for the reply! Really helpful! (: But I do have one question, how do I set the realm path? Because currently RLMRealm.setDefaultRealmPath() doesn't work anymore with RealmSwift.

Eg. from the website I quoted, in appDelegate.swift under applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions, the author used `let directory: NSURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.it.fancypixel.Done")!
let realmPath = directory.path!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("db.realm")
RLMRealm.setDefaultRealmPath(realmPath)`
Which doesn't work anymore. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! Oh yeah, that's one thing that's changed in Realm since that tutorial. All of the settings properties for a `Realm` were condensed into a `Configuration` object, including the file URL. The code for configuring a `Realm` is available on the Realm Swift docs page: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realm-configuration

Comment: Oh right, thank you! Got it to work now. Apologies for the newbie questions, I've only started programming recently. (:

Comment: No worries! That's quite okay! If you're still starting out, it's quite a lot to take in. All the best of luck! :)